# Visual Studio 2010 Runtime Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I wrote a tool that many users would use on their computers. I noticed however, that users who do not have visual studio installed, cannot open my executable. The error says that msvcp100.dll is missing. I found in internet a redistributable package from microsoft, that should apparently provide these dlls. My question is: is there another way to bypass this problem? Something like an option in the project properties?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can change a compiler setting to link the C++ standard library classes into your program instead of having a dependency on the DLL.  Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties.  Switch to the Release configuration (upper left).  C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.  Select /MT.

Only do this when you only have a single monolithic EXE.  When you use your own DLLs then you really need msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll so that the runtime library gets shared between all modules.

Comment: As indicated, don't do this.  Since you need those other DLLs to be copied to the machine as well, simply also copy msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll.  Having them in the same directory as the EXE and your DLLs is fine.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of C++ runtime and the target machine needs it. THere are couple of ways to address it.

Please check following link from Microsoft [MCVCP100.DLL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/3a007184-80e9-4e25-b5ad-ff31b028c051)