# The file MSVCP100D.dll is missing from the computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, opencv, release

What I'm having is that this error is displayed when I wanted to copy a exe debug project that I have created (which works witout any problems) to another machine (the error message is displayed).

According to the [question posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904213/msvcp100d-dll-missing), the best solution to get rid of the error message is to make a release and not a debug in the Configuration Manager.

Doing that, and when rebuilding the project with the RELEASE one, I'm having new errors in my project which were not included when doing the DEBUG.

For instance, one of them is :

```
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv\highgui.h': No such file or directory    c:\...\projects\...\ex\opencv.h 4
23  IntelliSense: identifier "IplImage" is undefined    c:\...\ex.cpp   80
```

Any feedbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVCP100.dll is part of the Microsoft Visual Studio 10 runtime. MSVCP100d.dll is the debug build of the same dll - useful for running your program in debug mode.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Basically it is a relatively new package and is not guaranteed to be on all systems, especially Windows XP, so you can distribute the required DLL files or the entire runtime with your program. EDIT: Keep in mind that debug builds are not meant to be distributed, so your program should not contain debug dll-s either such as MSVCP100d.dll.

Try downloading it, and then see what happens.

Also check out [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799783/visual-studio-2010-runtime-libraries)

Comment: Wrong: you can't distribute `MSVCP100D.dll`. It's not in redist.txt, the list of files you can redistribute. You can only redistribute the release version.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably added include paths for OpenCV to your project file. Unfortunately, Visual Studio by default makes such changes ONLY to the active configuration, which in your case was debug.

This rarely makes sense. Adding a logging library would be such a rare case, but you probably needs OpenCV in both debug and release builds.

Answer (score 0):

MSVCP100D.dll and MSVCP100.dll is part of the Microsoft Visual Studio 10 runtime, so if someone compile her/his programs with this package, then uninstall the package and install another one for example Microsoft Visual Studio 12 (2013). 
When trying to run her/his programs , then her/his will get the message that 'so and so... try to reinstalling the program to fix this problem'. this means you have to reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio 10.
the other way is to recompile your programs under the new package!